# We get receipts from our child care provider. Can we still claim a tax benefit even though they're not licensed?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, child-care, tax-deduction, tax-credit

We get receipts from our child care provider. Can we still claim a tax benefit even though they're not licensed?

*[**Note:** This is my paraphrased version of a [similar question](http://moms4mom.com/questions/2441/daycare-tax-question) I answered at [moms4mom.com](http://moms4mom.com).]*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Licensing wouldn't be related to whether you could use the caregiver's receipts as tax-deductions.

The IRS has a page worth checking out: [Top Ten Facts About the Child and Dependent Care Credit](http://www.irs.gov/newsroom/article/0,,id=106189,00.html), as well as [Publication 503: Child and Dependent Care Expenses (PDF)](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p503.pdf).  Specifically check out the section "Provider Identification Test" in Publication 503; it's relevant.

The amount you're deducting for child care needs to be **for** a "qualified person", e.g. **a dependent child under age 13**, per the IRS, but the caregiver – as far as the IRS is concerned – need not be specially qualified to provide child care.  However, the caregiver can't also be a dependent (e.g. your spouse or another child.)  See the resources above for details.

Licensing is likely enforced at a municipal or state level, separate from the tax code, and I imagine would be more concerned with the qualifications and conditions of the child care business operator.